# jQueryMobile-Timebox issue with overrideTimeFormat

Tags: jquery-plugins, jquery-mobile, datebox

I'm trying to use jQM-DateBox with data-option timebox in Force Clock Mode, to have a 24h range of hours, as shown here:
[enter link description here][jQM-DateBox Time]

I've simply copy pasted the code in my app

```
 <label for="mydate">Time </label>
 <input name="mydate" id="mydate" type="date" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "timebox", "overrideTimeFormat": 24}'>
```

and it still keep showing me AM/PM mode.
Anyone else noticed this behaviour? Any idea how to resolve it?

Note that in the link above (same code!) everything seems to work properly, and I have no other problems with other jQM-DateBox Mode.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean the picker shows 12hr mode, or the *return* value shows 12hr mode? (the picker seems to pick up that change - the return did not.  Investigating what should happen now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@J.T.Sage I meant the picker shows 12hr mode anyway

To anyone: I'm Italian so i "risolved" downloading this .js file [Italian .js script for timebox](http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.it.utf8.js)
and changing *timeFormat: 12* statement with *timeFormat: 24*. 
It's a trick, but it works.

Bye, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to override timeOutput too - i.e. "overrideTimeOutput":"%k:%M"

To be perfectly honest, I don't remember why I stopped doing the auto-switching - I think when I realized that the time output changes from locale to locale (if you are writing for a single locale, this is the easier way to handle it).  Otherwise, my assumption was that you'd need it in the format that the server expected, in which case you'd want to override it anyways.

Comment: This works perfectly: data-options='{"mode":"timebox", "useNewStyle":true, "overrideTimeFormat": 24, "overrideTimeOutput":"%k:%M"}', thanks dude